# AttributeError at /api/logout 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'auth_token'

Tags: django, api, authentication, token

I have successfully deployed the login view and it returns the token, but when i try to logout it returns the following error. I am new to this so cant figure out the reason.

These are my login and logout views.

```
class LoginUserView(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    new_data = serializer.data
    user = serializer.validated_data["user"]
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    #return response.Response(new_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return response.Response({"token": token.key},   status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    # return response.Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class Logout(GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # simply delete the token to force a login
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `permission_classes` class

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


class Logout(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [YourAuthClass] 

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # simply delete the token to force a login
        request.user.auth_token.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Note: You may need to set `authentication_classes` as well if you didn't set a default class.

Comment: I used permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication] in my Logout class. Now when I try to test in postman the logout api with Authorization and token, it generates 404 error. Can you help on this??

Comment: double-check the URL you are requesting, probably it might be wrong

Comment: Just confriming: I should put Authorization in key and Token "my token" under header in postman right?? URL is ok

Comment: If your authentication is not correct, DRF will send you either a `401` or `403`, not `404`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is coming when a user isn't authenticated properly. Use `request.is_authenticated` to check if a user is authenticated. If you are logged in and this error is coming, that  means your login system is incorrect, as Django is telling that `request.user` is `AnonymousUser`, which is the 'user' Django uses when nobody is logged in.

```py
class Logout(GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # simply delete the token to force a login
        if request.is_authenticated():
            request.user.auth_token.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Does this delete the token?? It returns 200 response but how do i know that the user has been logout?

Comment: If you mean token as the session info and cookies, yes. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout). You have to login with `auth.login` though.

Comment: My login us as shown above. I believe, I am trying to use token authentication in the login api view not session. I am new to this. But I am not sure which is being used in logout. Does, it delete the token and logout the user or does it end the session and logout the user?? Also, if its session, how long does the session last and how to determine it??

Comment: Can you clarify what token is? I am also a newbie to Django.

Comment: I've edited my answer now. Please check if this works.